# Loading Angular View

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, angular-routing, ng-view

Whenever we load `.html` files serving some controller in angular.
Does `angular` makes an `ajax` call to retrive that `html`.

Like this piecec of code.

```
 .state('home', {
              url: '/',
              templateUrl: '/Modules/Signin/signin.html',
              controller: 'SigninCtrl'
          })
```

I mean to ask while fetching signin.html

- Is an `ajax` call made?
- Or are they loaded as normal resources?
- If an `ajax` call is made where can i find some documentation written about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your that code executes, Angular first lookup the HTML template in `$templateCache` with the `id` `/Modules/Signin/signin.html`.

If it doesn't find that in the `$templateCache` then yes, **Angular will do an `AJAX` call using `$http` to get the HTML content** and **it will be loaded as normal resource** which should be located at the URL like:

```
http://example.com/Modules/Signin/signin.html
```

You can verify it in your browser's developer's console that an AJAX call was performed.

Read more about [$templateCache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache).

Basically, every template get's stored in the `$templateCache` when it is not stored already in the cache. So if you define the following in your `index.html` or any place (like where your `angular` is installed):

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/Modules/Signin/signin.html">
  <p>This is the content of the template</p>
</script>
```

Now as your Angular bootstraps, there will be a data in your `$templateCache` with id `/Modules/Signin/signin.html` so now your `state` code will not make any AJAX instead it will simply load the content defined above.

Answer (score 1):

I think a call is made, when I look into my own project. You have in the inspect element
 the network tab, as you reload you can see that every html part is loaded separately

Answer (score 1):

In `ui-router` at least (assuming the view is not in the templateCache) view HTML files are retrieved with a GET to the URL of the file, rather than with an AJAX call to an endpoint. In your case, it'll be a GET to `<your root URL>/Modules/Signin/signin.html` - you can see this in your browser's development tools.